# data-hover not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made the droupdown menu with data-hover attribute but that not working on hover at chrome browser. Version 57.0.2987.133 it working on chrome but not working in some systems.

```
  function configure(data) {
      // Determine if z-index should be managed

  var zIndex = Number(data.el.css('z-index'));
  data.manageZ = zIndex === defaultZIndex || zIndex === defaultZIndex + 1;

  data.config = {
    hover: Boolean(data.el.attr('data-hover')) && !touch,
    delay: Number(data.el.attr('data-delay')) || 0
  };
}
<pre>

<div class="dropdown" data-delay="5" data-hover="1">

<div class="menu-dropdown dropdown-toggle open">

<a href="#">test menu</a>

</div>

</pre>
```

Comment: Is it working on other browsers.?

Comment: Can't understand your question. When does your code work, and when does it not? Also, your attached code is just static html (`configure` function is defined but never used).